# JsonResponse and serializer, duplicate encodage?

Tags: symfony

So, i'm using Symfony2 and i have a special controller for all ajax request.

In each action i return a JsonResponse like that :

```
  $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
  return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true, 'params' => json_decode($serializer->serialize($params, 'json'))));
```

So, i a call my action from javascript, i can retrieve a nice json.

But i think there is a problem => I serialize my object, i json_decode the serialized object, and i jsonReponse the decoded serialized object.

How can i do that with a better way ?

Comment: You need to deserialize (to array) your `$params`.

Comment: Why don't you get rid of the whole 'json_decode($serializer->serialize($params, 'json')' and put simply '$params' instead?

Comment: $params is an object, i can't send a object without serialize before

Answer (score 0):

It will be more simple if you handle the success, error or whatever with the HTTP code. So your code will look like this.

```
return new Response($serializer->serialize($params, 'json'), 200, array('content-type' => 'application/json'));
```